# Dynamic load styles for themes angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to use different color themes (by env variables), but since `angular-cli` use his loader
and this not working:

```
styles: [
  require('./header.component.styl'),
  require('./header.component.${environment.theme}.styl')
]
```

I see **error:**

> can't resolve ./header.component.${environment.theme}.styl

what are the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Filenames import is not supported in Angular. You can create Static Filename let's say 'Colors.scss'. Inside the SCSS file, You can define global variable $env='appname'. You can use the $env variable in other Component SCSS files.

Comment: This require - not rly dynamic, after compile by angular-cli i waiting:
require('./header.component.dark-theme.styl')